# Laravel - Date variable doesn't keep its original value

Tags: laravel

here's a rough sample of my actual code:

```
$start_date = '01/02/2003';

for($i=1 ; $i<3 ; $i++){

$expiration_date = $start_date->addMonth(12);

}

dump($expiration_date ); //outputs 01/02/2005
dd($start_date); //outputs 01/02/2005
```

My Question is that why is my start_date variable also becomes the same with the expiration_date variable.

I need the start date at the end of the loop to still have its original value which is 01/02/2003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `addMonth` methods against a Carbon object it updates the object itself. 
Here's what you need to do:

```
$expiration_date = $start_date->copy()->addMonth(12);
```

The `copy` creates a new Carbon object

Check out the [documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)